# Is George Osborne breaking any official form of conduct by accepting the editor role at the Evening Standard?

Tags: united-kingdom

According to the Huffington Post George Osborne [faces demands to resign as the MP of Tatton](http://m.huffpost.com/uk/entry/uk_58cbda40e4b00705db4e84f2?ncid=fcbklnkukhpmg00000001), with Jeremy Corbyn looking to call a by-election in that constituency.

But is George Osborne actually breaking any official form of conduct by accepting the role? Are there rules against MPs accepting roles outside of their own as an MP?

I'm aware of the moral implications of accepting such a role and how the opposition can feel they won't receive fair treatment when being reported on within the Evening Standard (as noted in the article).

Comment: I initially assumed the last paragraph was satire as far as "fair treatment", but Poe's law strikes me again. Given overwhelmingly left and anti-Tory bias of most news media and reporters, concern that ONE reporter is a Tory seems... misplaced.

Comment: The Daily Telegraph and The Times are notably pro-Conservative.  Most tabloids sway viciously between parties according to market research to sell more papers.  The Independent is exactly as it states; an attempt to be Independent and remain free from bias wherever possible.  The only true left-leaning newspaper, openly liberal, is The Guardian.  @user4012 your premise is flawed.

Comment: @Venture2099 - tabloids aren't really "news media", although after John Edwards and National Enquirer happenings, I've gained more respect for their journalist-ing than for most MSM. Having read The Independent (the web version) I can definitely attest it's anything but. I'm not familiar with the other two but as per [Wiki brief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Times#Political_allegiance) The Times seems quite even-handed (and lately mostly endorsing Labour/Obama). You're quite right on The Telegraph, I apologize - but in US it's not as known as Guardian

Comment: Of course tabloids are news-media.  Your anecdotal evidence of The Independent does not eradicate 40 years of editorial independence including Conservative columnists.  The Guardian is knows as the The Guardian in the USA.

Comment: Nobody's mentioned that the largest papers in the UK, the Sun and the Mail, are the most strongly right-wing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_newspapers_in_the_United_Kingdom_by_circulation Metro is not very political and the Standard (ed. Osborne) is 4th.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No, there are no rules that prohibit Members of Parliament from holding other sources of employment.** In fact, many do.

However, MPs must not act as a "paid advocate", which means that they cannot take payment for speaking in the House or let it interfere with any parliamentary actions taken by the MP.

The [Commons Code of Conduct states that MPs must not act as a "paid advocate"](https://www.publications.parliament.uk/pa/cm201516/cmcode/1076/107606.htm):

> **1.** Paragraph 11 of the Code of Conduct for Members of Parliament provides:
>
> **11.** No Member shall act as a paid advocate in any proceeding of the House.

[This BBC article](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-31587588) summaries this and the rules regarding an MP's second job.

Comment: It might also be worth adding a comment about employment rules for former ministers: https://www.gov.uk/guidance/new-business-appointments-for-senior-public-servants

Comment: In addition, it isn't actually that unusual for a sitting MP to be an editor or part-time editor of a national newspaper or periodical. 


  https://blogs.spectator.co.uk/2017/03/mp-editor-done-before-spectator/